# deploy using delphi 11.3 returns E7176 invalid apksigner

Tags: android, deployment

I'm trying to deploy an application using Delphi 11.3 CE to an Android device 13, but returns the error :
Invalid or corrupt jarfile C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\CatalogRepository\AndroidSDK-2525-22.0.48361.3236\build-tools\33.0.3\apksigner.bat

I reinstalled Delphi and SDk , but nothing worked

I have this error...Please help to suggest. Thank you in advance.

Comment: According to the error message the programs that is responsible for signing the APK tries to access apksigner as JAR file but accidentally uses the batch file instead. Can you configure apksigner path somewhere? If yes point it to the jar file not the bat file.